# Is there a way to duplicate the data in a single MySQL request without redoing the calculation?

Tags: mysql, union

I must get some quite heavy operation with a query (let's name it r6) and then I would like to display r6 (no problems with that) and at the same time, display a grouped-by r6.

My idea was to use something like

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1 as field) AS r6
UNION SELECT COUNT(*) as field FROM (SELECT * FROM r6) AS r7 GROUP BY r6.some_field
```

to avoid the recalculation of r6, but I am not able to do it.

After some researches, I went using two temporary tables (because I can't reopen table ...)

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t_r1 (PRIMARY KEY(ID)) AS (SELECT * FROM r6);
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t_r2 AS t_r1;
SELECT FROM t_r1 UNION SELECT ...² FROM t_r2 GROUP BY some_field
```

(2): some ajustement made, but doesn't matter here.

Which works wonderfuly, but I can't make multiple statements from the php framework my company uses.

I could also duplicate the calculation of r6, but that is what I primarily wanted to avoid, for understandable efficiency issues :

```
SELECT ... FROM ... UNION SELECT ... FROM (same thing as first part) GROUP BY some_field
```

NB : Maybe i'm mistaken, and MySQL as a good boy does the duplication by itself without re-calculating everything. Which would please me, but I doubt so.

**Is there a way to duplicate the data in a *single request* without redoing the calculation ?**

Comment: I don't think so, but does it matter?

Comment: I don't know, it just does not feel right to copy/paste a query. Plus said query really uses a lot of subqueries each grouping by something. In the end, there's a lot of wasted time.